# Item cannot be installed or removed until the package catalogue is repaired

Tags: apt

After installing Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (meta-package) i receive an error

```
Item cannot be installed or removed until the package catalogue is repaired. Do you want 
to repair it
```

[image]

Ok, I thought... I'll just click repair and be done with it. After doing so I receive another error.

[image]

The full text reads:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 212945 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libasound2:i386 (from .../libasound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libasound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10_i386.deb (--unpack):
 './usr/share/alsa/cards/ICE1712.conf' is different from the same file on the system
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libasound2_1.0.25-1ubuntu10_i386.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.4-i386:i386:
 wine1.4-i386:i386 depends on libasound2 (>= 1.0.23); however:
  Package libasound2:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing wine1.4-i386:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.4:
 wine1.4 depends on wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package wine1.4-i386 is not installed.
  Package wine1.4-i386:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing wine1.4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine:
 wine depends on wine1.4; however:
  Package wine1.4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing wine (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.4-common:
 wine1.4-common depends on wine1.4 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package wine1.4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing wine1.4-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.4-amd64:
 wine1.4-amd64 depends on wine1.4-common (= 1.4-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package wine1.4-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing wine1.4-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

So I click OK and now I'm back to previous screen ("Item cannot be installed ...")

I click on cancel and go to the red circle on the top right on my screen and try to update from there and receive this error

[image]

After that I just get thrown these errors

[image]

[image]

[image]

So now I can't add or remove any programs on my system. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This is a way to try to fix broken dependencies, and some of the lines in your error code indicate that there are broken dependencies that do need fixing.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. Unfortunately this hasn't solved the issue. After running the command in terminal and restarting my computer, i am still faced with the same error i posted in the first image.

Does anyone have any other ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those previous responses will do the deed, you must first

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then repeat the

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue:

```
mv /usr/share/alsa/cards/ICE1712.conf /var/backup/usr/share/alsa/cards/ICE1712.conf
```

The file is different from what dpkg remembers so it fails. Moving the file away should fix the issue.