# Item cannot be installed or removed until the package catalogue is repaired. Gives error when I try to fix

Tags: apt, package-management

I know this question has been asked already at [Item cannot be installed or removed until the package catalogue is repaired](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130182/item-cannot-be-installed-or-removed-until-the-package-catalogue-is-repaired) but I am asking since I tried to run all these commands as told in the this solution which are:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But this didn't fix my problem.

When I run the last command which is:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get this error:

```
 Errors were encountered while processing: libc6-dev libc6-i386 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

P.S. I posted a separate post because i am new to this community and 10 points restriction minimum. :(